# Calender class gives different dates on different device

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I'm using following code. Values (hour, minute, second, date, month, year, day_of_week) are hardcoded for simplicity.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.DATE, 2);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.APRIL);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

String date = String.format(Locale.US, "%1$tA %1$tb %1$td %1$tY at %1$tI:%1$tM %1$Tp", c);
Log.e("date", date);
```

**Observation 1**

This code prints the the following on the Titanium S1 (Android 4.1.2)

```
E/date: Monday Mar 26 2018 at 10:00 AM
```

This code prints the the following on the Moto G4+ (Android 7.0), Moto G5+ (Android 7.0)

```
E/date: Monday Apr 02 2018 at 10:00 AM
```

**Observation 2**
This difference appears only on 2nd April & 2nd July to my knowledge. I am seeing the first day of month is Sunday for both the April and July month. It works fine for rest of the days

**Question**
1) Does the first day of month (MONDAY) cause this difference? Changing it to SUNDAY seems working on these two days. But I am not sure this works in all the scenarios.

This is affecting users on my app. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is date in the device set as same ?

Comment: @nits.kk, Yes date in device is same. The problem started today. So I have hardcoded the same date values.

Comment: I am not sure but may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42464293/504133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some test in JDK 7 and the results don't seem to be affected by `setFirstDayOfWeek`. Actually, it seems to be related to the JVM default locale (`java.util.Locale`).

When the default locale is Japanese or Thai, the final result is March. Somehow, the JVM default locale affects the internals of `Calendar`, in some misterious ways that, I must admit, are beyond my understanding. But anyway, one way to fix it is to set in the `Calendar` the same locale you used in the output:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

This fixed the issue for me.

### java.time API

This bizarre behaviour is one of the reasons to not use the old `Calendar` API (there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442), btw).

In Android, it's possible to use the [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). In API level 26, the [`java.time` classes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html) are available. For lower levels, you can use [this backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) - and in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) there are instuctions to configure it in Android.

With this new API, it's much easier - and less error prone - to get what you want. To build a specific date/time, use a `ZonedDateTime` class, and a `DateTimeFormatter` to convert it to a `String` in a specific format:

```
// April 2nd 2018, 10 AM
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 4, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MMM dd yyyy 'at' hh:mm a", Locale.US);
String formattedDate = dt.format(fmt); // Monday Apr 02 2018 at 10:00 AM
```

Note that the day of week is adjusted automatically, based on the day/month/year values provided.

To get the current date/time, just use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` (to get the current date/time in JVM's default timezone), or use `ZoneId.of("zone name")` to use a specific timezone - replace "zone name" with [any valid IANA zone's names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am about to try Local.US first. :)

Comment: In regards to 'Note that the day of week is adjusted automatically, based on the day/month/year values provided.' - My database has day of week values. I am suppose to get the time in millis from the the hour, minute, second, day of week. And time in millis required for the AlarmManager.

Comment: You first suggestion worked for me. More specifically, Local.US didn't work. According to my local constants, Local.France worked for me. The reason is I need MONDAY as a first day of week & the Local.France does the same. May be taking Local.US & MONDAY as a first day of week messing up the things because Local.US has SUNDAY as a first day of week. I am testing more scenarios. If everything works alright, I will accept your answer. Thank you very much for pointing me out a way.

Comment: Good Answer except one crucial issue: **Never use `LocalDateTime` for current moment**. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. That class does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. To capture the current moment, use only `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`. I must down-vote until that wrong advice is corrected.

Comment: @BasilBourque You're right, I should've used `ZonedDateTime`. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @uilon. Finally Local.France worked for me in all scenarios. I have accepted the answer. Thanks.